# You are not authorized to view this page while accessing my application on web

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have deployed a war file in tomcat6. I have started the tomcat server and access on the web(server:port/manager/html) works fine but when accessing my application it displays the following error,

```
You are not authorized to view this page.
```

catalina.out

```
20:04:25,711 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [pageviewErrorsLog]
20:04:25,713 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@34:25 - no applicable action for [BufferedIO], current pattern is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy][BufferedIO]]
20:04:25,714 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@36eb7331 - Will use zip compression
20:04:25,721 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[pageviewErrorsLog] - Active log file name: /home/user/work/software/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/logs/myapp-pageviewErrorsLog.txt
20:04:25,721 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[pageviewErrorsLog] - File property is set to [/home/user/work/software/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/logs/myapp-pageviewErrorsLog.txt]
20:04:25,721 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
20:04:25,721 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [dataWarehousePageviewFileLog]
20:04:25,722 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@54:25 - no applicable action for [BufferedIO], current pattern is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy][BufferedIO]]
20:04:25,722 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
```

What am I doing wrong? how do I solve this error?

Comment: This is not sufficient information. The log has nothing to do with the error.  Where is the error displayed? If it's in the browser, post a screenshot and include the HTTP status code.  Examine ALL the log files and look for a stack trace or other error messages, and post them as well.

Comment: The logs are don't have an error message... Tomcat server running properly... but my app is not working... Should I anything add on tomcat_users.xml or server.xml??

Comment: I have copied the sample.war file into the webapps directory of Tomcat, and I can access localhost:8080.

I need to open it in browser? So I accessed like "http://localhost:8080/sample" but it displays "You are not authorized to view this page."

Comment: Can anyone answer my question???

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough privileges to access your application, by GET/POST?

Check your authenticity by looking into web.xml file inside Sample directory under tomcat/webapps.